# Drop-down list's design is crashed with too many elements

Tags: d3.js, jquery-plugins, html-select

I have downloaded a JQuery-plugin for a searchable drop down list. Here is the [source](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Seachable-Option-List-with-Checkboxes.html)

I fill the list using D3.js. It works well for few elements, but when I want to load all elements (around 1200) the design is crashed and the list is displayed in the top so that I can't see the items and there is no scroll-bar.

Here how it looks like when I load the whole elements:

[image]

Here we can see from the developer tool in the browser that the data is loaded correctly:

[image]

The console shows these violations:

[image]

Here is my D3.js code:

```
d3.csv("Data/Symbols.csv").get(function (error, Symbolsdata) {
    if (error) throw error;

    d3.select("#my-select").selectAll(".option")
        .data(d3.map(Symbolsdata, function (d) { return d.CurrSymbol; }).keys())
        .enter().append("option")
        .text(function (d) { return d; })
        .attr("value", function (d) { return d; });
});
```

Html script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">


    <title> Crypto Trading Project</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sol.css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div class="collapse bg-light" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 py-4">
                  <select id="my-select" name="Cryptos"  multiple="multiple"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 py-4">
               From <input type="text" class="mt10px input" id="J-demo-04" value=""> To <input type="text" class="mt10px input" id="J-demo-05" value="">
                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" id="applyFilterButton" class="btn btn-dark">Apply</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 py-4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark box-shadow">
        <div class="container d-flex justify-content-between">
        <a href="#">Cryptos VA</a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader" aria-controls="navbarHeader" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>


    <main role="main">

    </main>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/date-time-picker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sol.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loadsol.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        // initialize sol
      $('#my-select').searchableOptionList({
        showSelectAll: true
      });

     //dateTimePicker

       $('#J-demo-04').dateTimePicker({
          limitMax: $('#J-demo-05')
      });

      $('#J-demo-05').dateTimePicker({
          limitMin: $('#J-demo-04')
      });

    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I have it work?

Comment: I suppose your question is how to make it work ? Maybe try at first not using the jquery plugin which seems to not handle too many nodes, and instead use the HTML5 datalist attribute : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: Yep exactly I want to have it worked. Well I need to have the search feature and the multi-selection from this plugin. It has the items but the list is appeared in the top (upwards) and it shows no scroll bar.

I am new to web development therefore I could not adjust the default value of the plugin or to overwrite it :)

Comment: There is also something with the timeout function in the source script (sol.js). I played with it a little bit,I have not received the violations messages any more. However, it's still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally figure it out. The idea is simply to fix the height of the active container and add a scroll bar. So I add in the sol.css file to the ***.sol-container.sol-active .sol-selection-container*** class these two css attributes:

```
height: 300px;
overflow-y: auto;
```